# To select a text box using index

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below is my code

```
<TR ID="oldContent"><TD><input type="text" name="code" id="oldContent"></TD></TR>
<TR ID="oldContent"><TD><input type="text" name="code"  id="oldContent"></TD></TR>
```

Here noth the text boxes have same name,id and type.Am not able to enter data to these text boxes

I have tried the below

```
selenium.type("xpath=//input[1][@name='code']",87767);
selenium.type("xpath=//input[2][@name='code']",67458);


selenium.type("xpath=//input[1][@name='code' and @type='text']",87767);
selenium.type("xpath=//input[2][@name='code' and @type='text']",67458);

selenium.type("xpath=//input[@name='code' and @type='text'][1]",87767);
selenium.type("xpath=//input[@name='code' and @type='text'][2]",67458);
```

None is working.can anyone help me with the xpath to find it?

Comment: selenium.type("xpath=(//input[@name='code' and @type='text'])[1]",87767);
selenium.type("xpath=(//input[@name='code' and @type='text'])[2]",67458);    Works

Comment: XPath isn't needed at all, but yes, you need to ensure you wrap it in parentheses when using indexers. CSS selector for second one: `#oldContent:nth-child(2)` or CSS selector for first one: `#oldContent:first-child`. Also, add your answer as an actual answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is as such:

```
<table id="someId">
  <tr id="oldContent">
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="code" id="oldContent" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="oldContent">
    <tr>
      <input type="text" name="code"  id="oldContent" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You would use:

```
selenium.type("css=table#someId > tr#oldContent:nth-child('1') input[type='text']",87767);
selenium.type("css=table#someId > tr#oldContent:nth-child('2') input[type='text']",67458);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath: //tr[@id='oldContent'][1]//input[@name='code']

Answer (score 0):

Try dom instead of x-path, it would be much simpler.